# Is my Tic-Tac-Toe design clean?

Tags: java, object-oriented

The following is an implementation of **Tic-Tac-Toe** game. I tried to incorporate `S` and `O` principles without violating `L`,`I`,`D` (*hopefully*) principles of `SOLID`. The main aim is to design in such a way that it is extensible so that any new feature additions in the future won't break the current architecture (Ex: If I Need to save Game info in DB in the future). I am mainly interested in how the components should be connected. Is my code clean? Any inputs are highly appreciated...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
    
interface IPlayer {
    int[] makeMove();
}

class Player implements IPlayer {
    private InputReader mInputReader;
    private BoardMovement mBoardMovement;
    private char mStyle;
    private String mName;

    public Player(InputReader inputReader, BoardMovement movement, char ch, String name) {
        mInputReader = inputReader;
        mBoardMovement = movement;
        mStyle = ch;
        mName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] makeMove() {
        int[] input = mInputReader.readInput();
        mBoardMovement.onMove(input[0], input[1], mStyle);
        return input;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
}

interface InputReader {
    int[] readInput();
}

class ConsoleInputReader implements InputReader {

    private final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    @Override
    public int[] readInput() {
        int[] move = new int[2];
        move[0] = SCANNER.nextInt();
        move[1] = SCANNER.nextInt();
        return move;
    }
}

interface BoardMovement {
    void onMove(int x, int y, char ch);
}

public class Board implements BoardMovement {
    protected final char[][] mBoard;
    protected int mSize;
    private final BoardMovement mListener = this;

    public Board(int n) {
        mBoard = new char[n][n];
        mSize = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMove(int x, int y, char ch) {
        mBoard[x][y] = ch;
    }

    public BoardMovement getBoardMovementListener() {
        return mListener;
    }
}

class GameState extends Board {
    Player mCurrentPlayer;
    Player playerOne, playerTwo;
    boolean isGameEnded;
    int winner;
    int moves;

    public GameState(int n) {
        super(n);
        moves = 0;
    }

    public void setPlayers(Player one, Player two) {
        playerOne = one;
        playerTwo = two;
        mCurrentPlayer = playerOne;
    }

    public void play() {
        int[] move = mCurrentPlayer.makeMove();
        checkWinner(move);
        moves++;
        if (isGameEnded) {
            winner = mCurrentPlayer == playerOne ? 1 : 2;
            return;
        }
        if (moves == mSize * mSize) isGameEnded = true;
        mCurrentPlayer = mCurrentPlayer == playerOne ? playerTwo : playerOne;
    }

    private void checkWinner(int[] move) {
        if (checkRow(move)) return;
        if (checkColumn(move)) return;
        checkDiagonal(move);
    }

    private boolean checkRow(int[] move) {
        int count = 0;
        char current = mBoard[move[0]][move[1]];
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
            if (mBoard[i][move[1]] == current) count++;
        }
        if (count == mSize) {
            isGameEnded = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkColumn(int[] move) {
        int count = 0;
        char current = mBoard[move[0]][move[1]];
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
            if (mBoard[move[0]][i] == current) count++;
        }
        if (count == mSize) {
            isGameEnded = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void checkDiagonal(int[] move) {
        int diag = 0, rev_diag = 0;
        char current = mBoard[move[0]][move[1]];
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
            if (mBoard[i][i] == current) diag++;
            if (mBoard[i][mSize - 1 - i] == current) rev_diag++;
        }
        if (diag == mSize || rev_diag == mSize) {
            isGameEnded = true;
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (char[] board : mBoard) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(board));
        }
    }

    // 0 -> draw , 1 -> player 1 , 2 -> player 2
    public int getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    public String getWinnerName() {
        return mCurrentPlayer.getName();
    }
}

class GameManager {
    GameState gameState;

    public GameManager(GameState gameState) {
        this.gameState = gameState;
    }

    public void startGame() {
        while (!gameState.isGameEnded) {
            gameState.play();
            gameState.print();
        }
        int winner = gameState.getWinner();
        if (winner == 0) System.out.println("The match is drawn");
        else System.out.println("The Winner is " + gameState.getWinnerName());
    }

}
```

Drive Code :

```
public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsoleInputReader consoleInputReader = new ConsoleInputReader();
        GameState gameState = new GameState(3);
        Player playerA = new Player(consoleInputReader, gameState.getBoardMovementListener(), 'X', "Player A");
        Player playerB = new Player(consoleInputReader, gameState.getBoardMovementListener(), 'O', "Player B");
        gameState.setPlayers(playerA, playerB);
        GameManager gameManager = new GameManager(gameState);
        gameManager.startGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that stands out to me is `class GameState extends Board {`.

When building for extensibility, you're imagining that all your classes get bigger and more complicated. Inheritance lets you spread the members of one class across multiple files. If all your files double in size, the complexity of `GameState` quadruples.

Here's an adaptation of your `GameState` that uses composition:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GameState {
    Player mCurrentPlayer;
    Player playerOne, playerTwo;
    boolean isGameEnded;
    int winner;
    int moves;
    // GameState *has* a Board, but it *isn't* a board
    // this means you aren't mixing Board state with GameState
    private final Board board;

    public GameState(int n) {
        board = new Board(n);
        moves = 0;
    }

    // unchanged
    public void setPlayers(Player one, Player two) {
        playerOne = one;
        playerTwo = two;
        mCurrentPlayer = playerOne;
    }

    public void play() {
        int[] move = mCurrentPlayer.makeMove();
        checkWinner(move);
        moves++;
        if (isGameEnded) {
            winner = mCurrentPlayer == playerOne ? 1 : 2;
            return;
        }
        // the logic of maximum possible moves is hidden behind a named method
        // that means that this class can focus on the business rule (moves == max moves)
        // and the board class can focus on implementation (max moves == width x height
        if (moves == board.getMaximumPossibleMoves()) isGameEnded = true;
        mCurrentPlayer = mCurrentPlayer == playerOne ? playerTwo : playerOne;
    }

    // unchanged
    // however, I would suggest that you make these check* methods static
    // and set the isGameEnded value here
    // because then you can move all the check methods into a separate file
    // which is another way to keep things small and well contained as your
    // classes grow
    private void checkWinner(int[] move) {
        if (checkRow(move)) return;
        if (checkColumn(move)) return;
        checkDiagonals(move);
    }

    private boolean checkRow(int[] move) {
        // See https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession
        // for a discussion on primitives vs micro objects
        Position position = Position.of(move);
        // getMarkerAtPosition: abstraction provides two things:
        // 1. a name that reveals the intention
        // 2. hides the implementation so you don't care how the board is encoded
        // Character: in addition to the primitive obsession points, 
        // using a boxed type here lets us use List instead of array
        // List lets us use stream, filter, etc.
        // which lets us write more concise code
        Character marker = board.getMarkerAtPosition(position);
        // I've split the for loop into two parts:
        // 1. find the row (this lives in board)
        // 2. check the row (stream/filter/etc.)
        List<Character> row = board.getRow(position.y);
        isGameEnded = row.stream().filter(x -> x.equals(marker)).count() == board.getBoardSize();
        // you had "if isGameEnded return true else return false", which simplifies to:
        return isGameEnded;
    }

    // same comments as checkRow
    // it's worth noting, though, that the checks now operate on lists of Characters
    // so instead of checking row, column, and each diagonal, you could instead 
    // get row, column, and each diagonal
    // and then for each of those four lists, check if any are complete
    private boolean checkColumn(int[] move) {
        Position position = Position.of(move);
        Character marker = board.getMarkerAtPosition(position);
        List<Character> column = board.getColumn(position.x);
        isGameEnded = column.stream().filter(x -> x.equals(marker)).count() == board.getBoardSize();
        return isGameEnded;
    }

    // same comments as rows/columns
    private void checkDiagonals(int[] move) {
        Position position = Position.of(move);
        Character marker = board.getMarkerAtPosition(position);
        // Previously, you iterated once. Now, this code iterates twice.
        // Since the size of the grid is constant and quite small, I don't 
        // think this affects performance.
        List<Character> upwardsDiagonal = board.getUpwardsDiagonal();
        List<Character> downwardsDiagonal = board.getDownwardsDiagonal();
        boolean isUpwardsDiagonalComplete = upwardsDiagonal.stream().filter(x -> x.equals(marker)).count() == board.getBoardSize();
        boolean isDownwardsDiagonalComplete = downwardsDiagonal.stream().filter(x -> x.equals(marker)).count() == board.getBoardSize();
        isGameEnded = isDownwardsDiagonalComplete || isUpwardsDiagonalComplete;
    }

    public void print() {
        board.getRows().forEach(row -> {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row.toArray()));
        });
    }

    // 0 -> draw , 1 -> player 1 , 2 -> player 2
    public int getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    public String getWinnerName() {
        return mCurrentPlayer.getName();
    }
}
```

`Board` class with new methods:

```
public class Board implements BoardMovement {
    // Although I've updated the methods to use Character instead of char
    // I didn't change the type of mBoard
    // You may find that storing the board as Character[][] makes things easier
    protected final char[][] mBoard;
    private int mSize;
    private final BoardMovement mListener = this;

    // unchanged
    public Board(int n) {
        mBoard = new char[n][n];
        mSize = n;
    }

    // unchanged
    @Override
    public void onMove(int x, int y, char ch) {
        mBoard[x][y] = ch;
    }

    // unchanged
    public BoardMovement getBoardMovementListener() {
        return mListener;
    }

    // the following are the new methods, extracted from GameState
    int getBoardSize() {
        return mSize;
    }

    int getMaximumPossibleMoves() {
        return mSize * mSize;
    }

    Character getMarkerAtPosition(Position move) {
        return Character.of(mBoard[move.x][move.y]);
    }

    List<Character> getColumn(int x) {
        List<Character> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int y = 0; y < mSize; y++) {
            result.add(Character.of(mBoard[x][y]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    List<Character> getRow(int y) {
        List<Character> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < mSize; x++) {
            result.add(Character.of(mBoard[x][y]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    List<Character> getUpwardsDiagonal() {
        List<Character> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
            result.add(Character.of(mBoard[i][mSize - 1 - i]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    List<Character> getDownwardsDiagonal() {
        List<Character> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
            result.add(Character.of(mBoard[i][i]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    List<List<Character>> getRows() {
        List<List<Character>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (char[] board : mBoard) {
            List<Character> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (char character : board) {
                row.add(Character.of(character));
            }
            rows.add(row);
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Supporting classes:

```
class Character {
    char value;

    private Character(char value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Character of(char value) {
        return new Character(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceof Character && this.value == ((Character) other).value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return java.lang.Character.toString(this.value);
    }
}
class Position {
    final int x;
    final int y;

    public static Position of(int[] moves) {
        return new Position(moves[0], moves[1]);
    }

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Previously, GameState relied on `mBoard` being `char[][]`. With this implementation, `GameState` relies on a few `Board` methods for accessing rows, columns, etc. You can implement those methods with any number of board formats. This lets the storage of the board vary independently of the game rules in GameState.

I think you can take this idea even further, working towards a version of your code where GameState reads almost like an English summary of the rules because the methods on `Board` are so expressive of the intent. The underlying principal is to increase the signal to noise ratio in the classes that have business rules. For you, that's `GameState`. Everything there that deals with implementation details like `[i]`, for loops, etc. is noise, and everything that deals with the rules of tic tac toe is signal. For example:

```
    int[] move = mCurrentPlayer.makeMove(); // signal
    checkWinner(move);  // signal
    moves++; // noise
    if (isGameEnded) { // signal..?
        winner = mCurrentPlayer == playerOne ? 1 : 2;  // noisy signal
        return;
    }
```

vs

```
makeMove(mCurrentPlayer);
if (boardStateDoesIndicateGameOver()) {
   winner = getPlayerIdentifier(mCurrentPlayer);
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What do your interfaces represent? `BoardMovement` is a name that represents an action, but it is implemented by `Board` which is named as if it represented a thing. Things representing actions sounds odd. Usually we expect things to implement abilities. `ChessPiece` might implement `Moveable` and so on.

The `BoardMovement` is the interface through which the players access the board. It should be named `Board`. Having the board provide an interface to itself via the `getBoardMovementListener()` method is completely counterproductive. You now need to have knowledge of the concrete implementation in order to gain access to the abstraction (this violates **D**).

I get a feeling that you are defining interfaces for the sake of having interfaces without putting too much thought into what methods they should provide. The reason for having interfaces is to provide the ability to change the implementation (the **L**) without having to change the code that uses the abstraction. For example, can you make a player that does not see from the screen what moves the opposing player made? E.g. a networked player? How do you communicate to that player that the game has ended?

You should separate the user interface responsibility from the game logic. Storing the `char` that represents the player on the board inside the `Player` class mixes the UI and game logic responsibilities into one component (violating **S**). Also, by doing this you expose the internal state of `Board` to the `Player` by allowing them to directly place their "mark" on the board (this is a code smell and a security issue). Who is there to prevent them from placing the wrong character? Why should you even allow them to place a wrong character on the board?

I suggest that you create a single `Board` interface that provides all methods a player needs to play the game: Read the board state and place a mark on the board. Create a implementation of `Board` that is only responsible for maintaining the state of the board. E.g. stores the marks, throws an exception if a player tries to place a mark on a reserved location, knows when the board is full (tie game). Create another implementation of `Board` that is responsible for detecting actual winning moves. Make that board a decorator for the one that stores the board state.

Be consistent in naming. If you use I-prefix in interfaces, use it in all interfaces. But I suggest that you don't. You should not clutter your code with unnecessary redundant stuff that is only useful to the lowest common developer, who gets surprised by the existence of something as fundamental as an interface...